# How to open macOS program in zsh with arguments like we did with bash?

Tags: macos, zsh

https://www.raywenderlich.com/511-command-line-programs-on-macos-tutorial

I'm making a terminal app using the above tutorial which was originally for the bash terminal. I downloaded the binary onto my computer and run it fine from terminal but I cannot open it with arguments. The old (bash) syntax was:

```
Panagram -a racecar carrace
```

But I'm new to zsh and can't seem to open the program with arguments:

```
open Panagram --args a racecar carrace
```

It opens the program but it doesn't pass in the arguments. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: The syntax isn't different between `bash` and `zsh`. `open` is not a `zsh` command; it's an external program used (among other things) to interact with Mac applications that can be double-clicked in the GUI.

Comment: @chepner why then if I just enter `Panagram` in the terminal I get `zsh: command not found: Panagram`? How do I open it without the `open` keyword?

Comment: If `Panagram -a racecare carrace` worked in `bash`, it should work in `zsh` as well. The only issue is whether your `PATH` variable is configured the same way in `zsh` as in `bash`, since different configuration files are used to initialize `zsh`.